# False warnings on Android Studio 3.3 (NDK)

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk, clang, clang-tidy

With the most recent 3.3 update, `Android Studio` seems to have a very annoying bug giving false warnings in C/C++ codes.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the IDE signals warnings on every bit operation incorporating an immediate value even if it's a positive number.

The only way getting rid of this annoyance is to "typecast" the immediate values to `uint32_t` which would be even more annoying.

Is there any option to suppress this kind of warnings in `Android Studio`? I do tons of bit operations in my codes, and it annoys the hell out of me right now.

Or it could be clang's fault, assuming any immediate value to be a signed one by default. Are there compiler options to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Android Studio [release notes](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/android-studio-33.html):

> Clang-Tidy Support for C++ - Android Studio now has support for
>   Clang-Tidy for C++ static code analysis. Similar to the current lint
>   support for Java and Kotlin in Android Studio, Clang-Tidy helps those
>   who have C++ in their Android app identify common coding errors and
>   bugs. Enable the inspection by going to Settings → Editor →
>   Inspections (Preference → Editor → Inspections for MacOS) . Learn
>   more.

So you can disable it from:

> Preferences->Editor->Inspections->General->Clang-tidy

Bonus:
You can find the list of Clang-Tidy options if you want to chose from:
http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/#using-clang-tidy

Comment: It seems to be the `hicpp-signed-bitwise` option that has been causing all the headache. I don't object compilers giving warnings on signed bitwise operations, but I find it really stupid mangling with positive immediate values. Could you tell me how to disable this particular option individually instead of disabling `clang-tidy` altogether? I tried to put `-hicpp-signed-bitwise` in the option list to no avail (it gets removed when reopened), and configuring via the dialogue box, I don't know what value to put. (neither 0 nor "Off" works)

Answer (score 3):

Would have commented on your original post but I don't have the rep. This is not a false warning as the 3 in your original code is in fact a signed integer literal. All integers literals are signed by default in C/C++. To create an unsigned literal you need to add a U suffix (eg. `3u` or `3U`). There's no need to use a cast to do so.